# Is it possible to create a reference with a variable in Java?

Tags: java, reference

I would like to know if its possible to create a reference using a variable for the name

Example:

Lets say I got a static reference somewhere in the code which holds number of users, at the begining its 0 ( `public static int countUsers = 0;` )

now each time I call the method adduser, it will use that variable on the refernce

```
public void addUser() {
     User newuser(countUsers) = new User();
     countUsers++;
}
```

Sort of "auto increment" the id. I want to do this without using SQL or any other 3rd party programs.  Only java.
Thanks!

Comment: Yes, you are doing that. `static` member variables are associated with the class, and not a specific instance.

Comment: why would one need SQL to increment variable? Is your code compiling?

Comment: SMA - it is, but I want to create references without storing them, when the program end it just shuts down and deletes all

I want to create references with name newuser0, newuser1 with the help of countUsers variable which is a primitive

Answer (score 0):

You need to set up your constructor for the `User` class to utilize this counter.  You can do this a couple of ways. If the counter is only used for `User` than you can move the static counter to the class itself and in the default constructor just assign and increment.  If it truly external, you'll need to create a constructor that takes in the count

```
public User(int count){
    this.count = count;
}
```

And then create your class like

```
User newUser = new User(countUsers++);
```

More than likely, what you want is

```
class User{
    private static int userCount = 0;
    private int userId;

    public User(){
        this.userId = userCount++;
    }

    public static int getUsersCount() { return User.userCount; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're truly trying to store the reference and not trying to do what I posted in the other answer then you might have to do a different approach.  Java passes primitive values by value.  Thus, you'll only be getting a *copy* of the value if you try to pass it in.  Instead, you'll need to wrap the global counter in a class which you can then access the global parameter from, or if you are using Java 8, you can string together some lambda magic to fetch the counter for you.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, I actually ment to do as you posted in the comment, that the reference will be created with a variable
that will will create reference int he following way
newuser0
nweuser1
etc...

Comment: Creating a new variable with a dynamic name isn't very useful as you won't be able to use it in your code.  I believe what you are trying to do is create a  List<User> and then append your newly created User to that List.  Each User would have their own ID if you implemented like in my other answer, and you'd be able to access all of the created User's from the List.